# Splitting items in a list - R

Tags: r

I have some items in my list that have / built in to them.
I want to split and duplucate them, e.g
a/b/c z -> becomes 
a z
b z
c z

This is an example of my data but i don't have a clue on how to start. Any thoughts?

```
structure(list(keyword = c("deltoid muscle", "teres major/minor muscle", 
"latissimus dorsi muscle", "serratus anterior/posterior superior/inferior muscle", 
"levator scapulae", "rhomboid major/minor muscle", "erector spinae muscle", 
"thoracolumbar fascia.", "Bone â\200“", "Clavicle:")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

e.g The output of

```
"rhomboid major/minor muscle"
```

should be

```
"rhomboid major  muscle"
```

and

```
 "rhomboid minor muscle"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this works for all cases when only one `\` is present

```
sub("(.*) (\\w+)/(\\w+) (.*)", "\\1 \\2 \\4; \\1 \\3 \\4", keyword[,1])

 [1] "deltoid muscle"                                                                                                                                        
 [2] "teres major muscle; teres minor muscle"                                                                                                                
 [3] "latissimus dorsi muscle"                                                                                                                               
 [4] "serratus anterior/posterior superior muscle; serratus anterior muscle; serratus anterior/posterior superior muscle; serratus posterior inferior muscle"
 [5] "levator scapulae"                                                                                                                                      
 [6] "rhomboid major muscle; rhomboid minor muscle"                                                                                                          
 [7] "erector spinae muscle"                                                                                                                                 
 [8] "thoracolumbar fascia."                                                                                                                                 
 [9] "Bone â€“"                                                                                                                                              
[10] "Clavicle:"
```

we can use this awkward stack to get the case when 2 `\` are present

```
output <- sub("(.*) (\\w+)/(\\w+) (.*)", "\\1 \\2 \\4;\\1 \\3 \\4", keyword[,1])
output <- sub("(.*) (\\w+)/(\\w+) (.*)", "\\1 \\2 \\4;\\1 \\3 \\4", unlist(strsplit(output,";")))
output <- unlist(strsplit(output,";"))


    > output
 [1] "deltoid muscle"                     "teres major muscle"                
 [3] "teres minor muscle"                 "latissimus dorsi muscle"           
 [5] "serratus anterior superior muscle"  "serratus posterior superior muscle"
 [7] "serratus anterior inferior muscle"  "serratus posterior inferior muscle"
 [9] "levator scapulae"                   "rhomboid major muscle"             
[11] "rhomboid minor muscle"              "erector spinae muscle"             
[13] "thoracolumbar fascia."              "Bone â€“"                          
[15] "Clavicle:"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table`-approach. I've been struggling with this one, so the code is MOST SURE not the best/most elegant. It should work no matter how many ../.. choices are presented in a string (not tested).

I'm open for all improvements..

but it seems to get the job done...

**sample data**

```
library( data.table)
DT <- structure(list(keyword = c("deltoid muscle", "teres major/minor muscle", 
                           "latissimus dorsi muscle", "serratus anterior/posterior superior/inferior muscle", 
                           "levator scapulae", "rhomboid major/minor muscle", "erector spinae muscle", 
                           "thoracolumbar fascia.", "Bone â\200“", "Clavicle:")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**code**

```
setDT( DT )

#cut string into parts
DT[, paste0( "part_", 1:length( tstrsplit( gsub("([a-z]+\\/[a-z]+)", "~\\1~", DT$keyword ), "~" ) ) ) :=
               tstrsplit( gsub("([a-z]+\\/[a-z]+)", "~\\1~", DT$keyword ), "~" ) ][]

#replace all NA with %-sing (or any other sign that does NOT appear in your data!!)
#it can be removed later on
DT[ is.na(DT) ] <- "%"

#split all .../... values to a vector
cols = grep( "^part_", names(DT), value = TRUE )
DT[, (cols) := lapply( .SD, strsplit, "/" ), .SDcols = cols ][]

#now throw it all together
answer <- data.table::rbindlist( lapply( transpose( DT[, .SD, .SDcols = cols ] ), function(x) do.call( expand.grid, x ) ) )
answer[, final := Reduce( function(...) paste0(..., sep = ""), .SD[, mget(cols)])]

#now remove the "%"-sing
gsub( "%", "", answer$final )
```

**output**

looks all right...

```
# [1] "deltoid muscle"                     "teres major muscle"                 "teres minor muscle"                
# [4] "latissimus dorsi muscle"            "serratus anterior superior muscle"  "serratus posterior superior muscle"
# [7] "serratus anterior inferior muscle"  "serratus posterior inferior muscle" "levator scapulae"                  
# [10] "rhomboid major muscle"              "rhomboid minor muscle"              "erector spinae muscle"             
# [13] "thoracolumbar fascia."              "Bone â€“"                           "Clavicle:"
```

Comment: I tried to make it into a function, but no luck. What's your take?

Comment: ``` remove_quotes <- function (DT) {
  setDT( DT )
  
  ...
  return(DT)
} ```